# If my /proc/filesystems doesn't contain fat32 it doesn't support it?

Tags: mount, filesystem

```
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cpuset
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   devpts
        ext3
        ext2
        ext4
nodev   hugetlbfs
        vfat
nodev   ecryptfs
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
nodev   pstore
nodev   mqueue
```

This is the content of my /filesystems file.

As described by http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html This file contains all types that my system supports.

I wan't to mount with that function a fat32 filesystem which my system is able to acces when it is autoconnected even if there is no fat32 in the file.

strange fact 1: While I'm writing this post I got notified by gedit that the file has been changed on disk and about I want to reload it. Does it mean my system can change on the fly the support of the filesystems?

And now to the question I'm asking about in this post:

Is there an system mentioned in the file that includes fat32? I was guessing it could be expected that vfat has to be used. But that would be strange and more so had to be the other way round, as fat32 is the next version of vfat and not the otherway around.

Answer (score 2):

The `vfat` provides fat32 support.